# Python creating new columns, set as np.nan, working in 3.9.6 but not in 3.7.3

Tags: python, pandas

```
zed = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]})
zed[['t1_line_proj', 't2_line_proj']] = np.nan
```

In python 3.9.6, this is running fine, creating 2 columns `t1_line_proj` and `t2_line_proj` both filled with NaN values.

In python 3.7.3, this is returning the error `KeyError: "['t1_line_proj' 't2_line_proj'] not in index"`.

Anyway to get this working in python 3.7.3? Or should we just update to 3.9.6?

Comment: It's just working fine on ` Python 3.6.8` then i think it should also work on later updates, i don't see any reason of not working.

Comment: Do you have the same version of pandas with both python version?

Comment: I'm on 3.6.3 and the above lines work fine.

Comment: @SMeznaric, Ben is asking for pandas version not python.

Comment: @KarnKumar I was not replying to Ben. Just adding my 2c that the above code works on 3.6.3.

Comment: thats nice, but to know what its not working may be pandas version, as i know the works pretty well with 3.6,3.7,3.9 of python.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why it works in 3.9.6 and not 3.7.3, but I've updated the code to this which works in both... pretty straightforward I would say.

```
zed = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]})
zed['t1_line_proj'] = np.nan
zed['t2_line_proj'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as well:

```
zed.assign(t1_line_proj=np.nan, t2_line_proj=np.nan)
```